# JSP page is being cached forever in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I've done all things mentioned here [jsp page is cached, can not change it, tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603288/jsp-page-is-cached-can-not-change-it-tomcat), but still the same page. what else should I consider?

Comment: Do you mean including with using `<%@ include file="src"/>`?, if yes, I have included JSP files.

Comment: Are you using local tomcat instance, or is your tomcat server located in different timezone?? the tomcat will recompile your jsp page only when the generated class file's timestamp is older than your jsp file. This sometime's gives problem when server is located in different timezone.

Comment: rao_555 I', using local instance, and i've not changed tomcat's timezone, I think it's the same with my machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using `<%@ include file="someother.jsp" %>`, I suggest `touching` the parent JSP as well as the included files.

The `<%@ include file="file.jsp" %>` includes files at compile time. So unless your parent file is changed, a recompilation is not forced.

If you use `<jsp:include />` however, the inclusion is carried out at runtime, ensuring that you always get a fresh copy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `touching` ? Why is it bug or feature :)?

Comment: `touch file.jsp` if on unix. If you're on Windows, just open the file, add a space or new line and save it. That's how it is supposed to work :)