# How to include resources in JSP and not to overhead service-method?

Tags: java, jsp, include

I am working on a highload project using JSP with a great amount of includes of other resources on pages (jsp, jspf).

It is known that there are 2 ways to use include in JSP: static - **<%@include %>** and dynamic - **<jsp:include />** (or JSTL equivalent <c:import />).

But they both have Cons.

For example, the static import can cause collision of variable names from the main page. And dynamic import is inferior in performance.

I would like to use something that is not overhead for service method and at the same time independent from the rest of the code.

In the most narrow places, we had to place html-code in java-code:

```
public String getHtml() {
    return “<div class=’entity’>” + … + “</div>”;
}
```

And in JSP we do something like:

```
<jsp:getProperty name="someEntity" property="html" />
```

This solves problems with includes, but it’s a horrible code-style and it’s very difficult to refactor.

It seems that the ideal solution would be to code special tag library, something like:

```
<entitytag>
    <parameter name=’param1’ class=’java.util.String’ />
    <parameter name=’param2’ class=’mypackage.Entity’ />
    <tagbody>
        <div class=’entity’>…</div>
    </tagbody>
</entitytag>
```

That will be translated into:

```
static public void entitytag(String param1, Entity param2, JSPWriter out) {
    out.write(“<div class=’entity’>”);
    …
    out.write(“</div>”);
}
```

In JSP this invocation will look like:

```
<mylib:entitytag param1=’someString’ param2=’someEntity’ />;
```

And in the service method:

```
MylibClass.entitytag(param1, param2, out);
```

So, my question is the next: are there any approaches to make such trick gracefully? Maybe using third-party libraries?

Comment: I really don't understand the problem. What's wrong with using include? Is it somehow slow?

Comment: Yes, dynamic include is much more slow than static.

Comment: Isn't that just a method call once the servlet is compiled? Do you got any link to back this up?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro8.html

Comment: J2EE 1.3? You're more than 10 years lost in history =\. By the way, please provide a **real example** instead of just thoughts in order to receive **real help**.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry, I do not understand what kind of example you need.
If you try this for example: http://pastebin.com/KRjYpy4A you'll get numbers that differ by **3 orders**.
That's what i got: 5433, 3731260; 2415, 6885067; 1208, 3072909 and so on.
WEB-INF/file.jsp was empty in my case. So **JspRuntimeLibrary.include()** is huge overhead when compared with the inline transtaion. 
When delays accumulate page starts to work 3-4 times slower.
PS: I use JAVA 7, JSP 2.2

Comment: I don't understand what benefit you hope to gain, over <%@include %>

Comment: @NimChimpsky performance first of all.

Comment: A compile time inclusion takes 1208 nanoseconds, apparently. There will always be some slight overhead - some processing of the file is required. But 1.208e-6 seconds would not be a problem in my company, and I doubht you or I could get it any quicker anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the solution is ever doing html in java.

And the normal jstl include is fine, in what way do you think you can improve performance ?

Comment: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663736/how-to-include-resources-in-jsp-and-not-to-overhead-service-method#comment22237768_15666790)

Comment: @user2216318 and what sort of measurable performance increase do you expect to gain ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663736/how-to-include-resources-in-jsp-and-not-to-overhead-service-method#comment22258276_15663736

Comment: @user2216318 you have shown that the static include is faster, we knew that

Comment: so, my question is: Why not eliminate the use of things like **JspRuntimeLibrary.include()**? JSP translation\compilation can be done much more efficient.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8834496/106261 , they are different either inclusion at runtime, or inclusion at compile time - I use compile time inclusion 99% of the time. But would not rule out using runtime inclusion for specific use cases. I am not clear what you are suggesting... a different api for performing compile time inclusion ?

Comment: Well, i'm not suggest yet, I just wanted to clarify if such api exist. Because it's obvious to me that JSP-snippet translation into single method will be much more efficient, than using mechanisms of dynamic import. And it can be done independently for changing, just like dynamic imports. So, I guess I got my answer =)

Comment: @user2216318 I am not clear what this means "And it can be done independently for changing"

Comment: Sorry, for my ENG. You post the link in which answerer told that dynamic jsp:include ensuring that we always get a fresh copy of JSP. So I meant that approach that i suggest can be done just as well. I hope this is clear...

Comment: @user2216318 ok, so you think you can write an mechanism of runtime inclusion (where it gets compiled each time it is included) that performs as fast as normal compile time inclusion, where it is compiled once. You are wrong.

Comment: Actually, JSP do not compiles each time we jsp:include it)

Comment: @user2216318 ok, but it is resovled/translated ... the point remains the same. It will never be quicker due to the extra processing required.

Comment: We have strayed from the topic. In fact I do not care about fresh versions of files. I just want convenient translator of static\inline includes.

Answer (score 0):

When a jsp is viewed the first time, it is turned into a java class and compiled - including any includes and/or imports, all of it becomes one class.

So, a ton of includes might impact performance the first time a page is viewed, but after that, it's essentially the same as invoking a servlet.

If you're on tomcat, drill down the tomcat/work directory to see what has become of your carefully written jsps.

Comment: Dynamic include is not compiled in the servlet as static include. That's why it's called "dynamic".
When we do <jsp:include /> we got in servlet something like:
JspRuntimeLibrary.include(request, response, "/WEB-INF/file.jsp", out, true);

instead of usual out.write('...');

Exactly this JspRuntimeLibrary.include() call decrease performance of the servlet.

So my idea is to make call of static method, with lightweight out.write('...'), in service method.
But still to be able to make html layout in usual JSP.