# error in running jsp file in tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to run a jsp file (test1.jsp) on tomcat server and it gives error!!
test1.jsp:

```
<html>
   <head><title>Hello World</title></head>
     <body>
       Hello World!<br/>    
      <%@ page import="neww.*" %>
      <% Simple demo = new Simple();
      out.println("Current date : " + demo.retur());%>
      <%
         out.println("Your IP address is " + request.getRemoteAddr());
      %>
     </body>
</html>
```

Simple.java:

```
package neww;
import static com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ReadWrite.READ ;
import static com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ReadWrite.WRITE ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ReadWrite ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Dataset ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBFactory ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.sse.SSE ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.update.* ;
import java.util.*;
public class Simple{
public String retur(){
/*String query1;
            query1="hjcooljohny75@gmail.com";
        //query1 = (String)(subjectentry.getText());
            String s="SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x <TO:> '"+query1+"'}";
          //   subjectoutput.setText(s);
            String directory = "MYDATABASES/DATA2" ;
            Dataset ds = TDBFactory.createDataset(directory) ;
            Model model = ds.getDefaultModel() ;
           ds.begin(ReadWrite.READ) ;
             QueryExecution qExec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(s, ds) ;
           ResultSet rs = qExec.execSelect() ;
           String x=rs.toString();
          String[] arr = null;

            while (rs.hasNext()) {
                QuerySolution qs = rs.next();
                String rds = qs.get("x").toString();
               // String em = (String)rs.getString(0);
               //arr = em.split("\n");
               //for (int i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
              return rds; 

           }
             //if(rs==null)
  */              //subjectoutput.setText("sorry!!");
     String s="hi";
     return s;
}
}
```

my directory structure is :
  /check/WEB-INF/classes//neww/Simple.java 
/check/WEB-INF/classes//neww/Simple.class
error in tomcat:
`

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Simple
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:905)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:834)
    org.apache.jsp.test1_jsp._jspService(test1_jsp.java:82)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)`
```

I think this error probably have to do with package , I am really stuck on this ...Help!!

Comment: clean the tomcat cache and try again. It might help in [JSP page is cached, can not change it, tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603288/jsp-page-is-cached-can-not-change-it-tomcat)

Comment: I think the issue is with where you have put Simple.java, as the error suggests, It can't find Simple.java. I tried this on Eclipse: 1- put test1.jsp in WebContent, 2- put Simple.java in "models" package inside  Java Resources/src. 3- Changed <%@ page import="models.*" %>

Didn't get any errors.

Comment: I think the problem is something else as other java file in same folder is working fine!!

Answer (score 0):

You should check your classes directory under WEB-INF directory. It is clear from exception that server is trying to load your class but it is not available in class path.

your application structure should be something like this

APP_NAME
  WEB-INF
    classes
        Package structure 
            -> you class file should be here..

In case you are deploying your app as war file then extract the war and check the class file location.

Generally eclipse create bin folder to store the class file check it if your class file is also there then change it to classes folder under WEB-INF